# Site recommendation for FontForge scripting?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm a Python developer dabbling in font creation for the first time as a side hobby using FontForge 2017-07-31 over XQuartz 2.7.11 on MacOS 10.12.6

My goal is to create a series of novelty fonts for personal use. I can do the tasks manually via the UI, but I need to automate these tasks via scripting and am not sure whether the menu item in question ("Insert Text Outline...") has a corresponding API call.

I'm open to using tools other than FontForge if necessary, though free is certainly preferable.

What's the best community for such a query? The closest match I [posted under was TEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388898/fontforge-scripting-insert-text-outlines-dialog), but doesn't feel quite right so wondering if there's a better...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font design questions are on topic on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Have a look through the [font-forge](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-forge) and [font-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-design) tags, which may be of help to you. Automation and scripting questions are on-topic (we don't have many FontForge scripting questions but do have, for example, a lot of [Adobe Illustrator scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustrator-scripting) questions so I see no problem with the former).

I'm not entirely sure about TEX's scope, but I'd assume the question would be off-topic there as it has nothing to do with [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX).

Comment: thanks - sounds good! should I delete the original question under TEX or self-answer?

Comment: I would probably delete it on TEX (assuming it's off-topic there, but I'm not 100% certain on that)